# Find the position of the first occurrence of a character in a string after a specific position

Tags: php

I would like to find the position of the first point after the @ character:

```
blabla jim@gmail.com blabla.bla bla
```

I know that the @ is at position 54, so the result would be 60.

Comment: The third argument of `strpos` is offset...

Comment: strpos(). that's it?

Comment: `first point`, e.g. first `.`?

Comment: Just copy your title into google!

Comment: I was looking everywhere, didn't know strpos had an offset parameter. Thanks

Comment: @erdomester you should always lookinto PHP Manual first. ;-)

Comment: `strpos($str, '.', strpos($str, '@'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes the first dot '.', but let strpos start searching after the first position of the at '@'.

```
strpos($string, ".", strpos($string, "@"))
```

Comment: Note as well it returns the [position in the total string](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DENV8Y), not the position minus the offset (just in case that's not clear).

Comment: That is correct, but this was also what the poster asked for. He wanted to receive the position 60 if the position of the '@' was at 54.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong (I upvoted the answer). I was simply adding that as a statement.